# How to fix "builddir not recognized as an internal or external command." error when building libiconv?

Tags: windows, build, mingw, libiconv

I'm trying to compile *libiconv* under Windows 7 using mingw. I've been following this tutorial: https://blog.inventic.eu/2010/11/how-to-compile-open-source-libraries-under-windows-using-mingw/

However when I try to *make*, it throws an error.
Here's a sreenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu4eD.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Some packages have build instructions for Windows included in the package.

In particular, GNU libiconv has a file `README.windows` or `INSTALL.windows`.

MSYS is **not** a supported environment for building GNU libiconv.

Comment: Do you mean for the newer versions of libiconv? Because in the tutorial MSYS is used to compile libiconv. What do you suggest then?